# How can I find out why users will lose login with session in php?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Someone asked me to help out with an already made user system, with file archive, chat, links, news articles etc. They use it for company resources. They had the system with PHP 5.3 and upgraded recently to PHP 5.5, with mostly the same settings. I have gone through all changes between PHP 5.3 to 5.4 to 5.5, and removed features and changed features and can't find any answers regarding the faults.

The system is on a "rental server", and includes a lot of files and I don't have the ability og possibility to copy it all and create my own server (also because I can't reproduce when several users are logged in) and I cannot install extra features to the server either. I heard about PHP Compatibility (PHPCS), but I can't figure out how to use it on the server or with FTP.

When the users log in, they enter username and password, and check that information against the user register in the MySQL database. If ok, the user is logged in. Since this page uses session() it should remember the session information, but it feels that it's random when the user is logged out. And the user doesn't know this before updating the page (with F5).

The page uses a javascript/php chat system. You enter a message and the message will be put into MySQL but uses a javascript system (not programmed by me) to update the page. It also uses Chrome notification system to update the users. So when a persons username is written in the chat, that person will get a chrome notification on his/hers computer. After this bug, not all get that notification and when they then update their chrome with F5, the chat updates with more information. And sometimes when F5 is sendt, they have to log in again!

How can I find the error or the hole? I have searched all the files for compability errors, but nothing is found. Is there scripts that I can upload to check the system or what can I do?

Comment: If you're running with apache, there might be some clue at apache error or access log.. It's hard to tell what's going wrong without seeing the actual code..

Comment: login session lose because they close the browser

Comment: Check apache and php error log (enable error logging for `E_ALL`, if it isn't enabled yet).

Comment: what would be useful is: 1. access/error logs on server, 2. console logs on browser, 3. code

Comment: It depends on the server configuration or the relevant directives (session.gc_maxlifetime) in php.ini. Typically the default is 24 minutes (1440 seconds), but your webhost may have altered the default to something else.
please go through the official link about php session this will help u to figured out the problem.
[Php.net/sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

Comment: I have tried session.gc_maxlifetime to a higher number. Right now it is: session.gc_maxlifetime = 86400 and also: session.cache_expire = 1440. On the comment about closing the browser, they don't close them :)